# Cocoa window doubles in size when replacing view

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to replace one View (and its ViewController) by a different one at runtime. Now when I do that, the old View disappears from the window, but the new one does not appear and the window becomes double its original width.
If I switch to full screen, I can see the new View quite small in the bottom left corner of my application's window.

Does anybody have a clue why this happens? I have been trying everything for hours now, but I cannot seem to find the reason why this happens.

For replacing the View (as well as its ViewController) I use the following code:

```
func exchangeDiashowViewController(for newDiashowViewController: NSViewController) {
    if let oldDiashowViewControllerAsStateObserver = self.diashowViewController as? DiashowStateObserver {
        DiashowManager.sharedInstance.remove(stateObserver: oldDiashowViewControllerAsStateObserver)
    }
    if let oldDiashowViewControllerAsSpeedObserver = self.diashowViewController as? DiashowSpeedObserver {
        DiashowManager.sharedInstance.remove(speedObserver: oldDiashowViewControllerAsSpeedObserver)
    }

    if let newDiashowViewControllerAsStateObserver = newDiashowViewController as? DiashowStateObserver {
        DiashowManager.sharedInstance.add(stateObserver: newDiashowViewControllerAsStateObserver)
    }
    if let newDiashowViewControllerAsSpeedObserver = newDiashowViewController as? DiashowSpeedObserver {
        DiashowManager.sharedInstance.add(speedObserver: newDiashowViewControllerAsSpeedObserver)
    }

    self.view.replaceSubview(self.diashowViewController.view, with: newDiashowViewController.view)
    self.diashowViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
    self.addChildViewController(newDiashowViewController)

    self.diashowViewController = newDiashowViewController

    let centerHorizontallyConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.diashowViewController.view, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let centerVerticallyConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.diashowViewController.view, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.diashowViewController.view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.diashowViewController.view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

    self.view.addConstraints([centerHorizontallyConstraint, centerVerticallyConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
}
```

I really hope someone has an idea. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `self.view.replaceSubview()` is the problem.

I got everything working by using

```
self.diashowViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
self.view.addSubview(newDiashowViewController.view)
```

instead.